# How can I compute the derivative of a variable after it is solved using NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a 4th-order(with respect to x and 2nd-order with respect to t) pde which is solved easily using NDSolve for the variable v[x,t]. Now, I also want the value of 3rd-order partial derivative of v[x,t] with respect to 'x'. I am trying to write it as Fy = D[v[x,t], x, x, x] but, it's not giving Fy as a function of x and t. How to do it? Here is the code:

```
l = 0.15;
wc = 125.663706; 
l1 = 0.50;
a = 3.16*(10^(-4));
e = 200*(10^9);
d = 7800;
j = 8*(10^(-9)); (* Moment of Area *)
m = d*a*l1;
ms = 0.25;(* Slider Mass *)
al = wc*t;
be = ArcSin[l*Sin[al]/l1];
Cy = 1000; (* Beam Damping coefficient *)

Ti = 0.00000001;
Tf = 0.15;

PX = l*Cos[al] + x*Cos[be] + v[x, t]*Sin[be]; (* 'P' is any point on the connecting rod *)
PY = l*Sin[al] - x*Sin[be] + v[x, t]*Cos[be];

BC2 = v[0, t] == 0;
BC4 = Derivative[2, 0][v][0, t] == 0;
BC5 = Derivative[2, 0][v][l1, t] == 0;
BC6 = v[l1, t] == 0;

IC1 = v[x, Ti] == 0;
IC4 = Derivative[0, 1][v][x, Ti] == 0;

EQ2 = -e*j*D[v[x, t], x, x, x, x] == d*a*(Sin[be]*D[PX, t, t] + Cos[be]*D[PY, t, t]) + Cy*D[v[x, t], t]; 


sol = NDSolve[{EQ2, BC2, BC4, BC5, BC6, IC1, IC4}, {v}, {x, 0, l1}, {t, Ti, Tf}]

Fy = -e*j*D[v[x, t], x, x, x]

Plot[Evaluate[{v[l1/4, t]} /. sol], {t, Ti, Tf}]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please, always post the code that led to your problem (in copyable form!). Otherwise, this is going to become a guessing game.

Comment: Have done it. Thanks!

Comment: `%` is always the _last_ result. So in the way you use it, it is not the return value of `NDSolve` any more. Actually, using `%` is often the cause of undesired behavior. Better assign the result of `NDSolve` to a separate variable (e.g. `sol`) and use `Plot[Evaluate[{v[l1/4, t]} /. sol], {t, Ti, Tf}]`.

Comment: I don't understand the last Plot command , especially the substitution `/. Fy`.

Comment: @Henrik! I have changed it to 'sol'. But, my problem is that I can't find the value of 'Fy'.

Comment: @Ulrich, I need the value of Fy so, I wrote the 2nd last equation in the code above. In the last command, there was a '%' earlier which I have modified now. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @ Ayush Burnwal You want to plot `Fy`???

Comment: @UlrichNeumann yes I have to.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I don't think your suggestion worked, the output is something like this: {-1600 InterpolatingFunction[{0., 0.5}, {1. x 10^(-8), 0.15}},<>][x,t]}

Comment: I don't know whether I fully understand what you are asking me to do. I am totally new to mathematica, I apologize if I am doing any stupidity. This is what I have written: Plot[Fy[l1, t], {t, Ti, Tf}]

Comment: @AyushBurnwal Anyways, Ulrich's solution is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the code `sol=...` to

```
V = NDSolveValue[{EQ2, BC2, BC4, BC5, BC6, IC1, IC4}, {v}, {x, 0,l1}, {t, Ti, Tf}][[1]]
```

you get an interpolation object V which can be plotted directly ( for example the expression you called Fy)

```
Plot[Derivative[3, 0][V][l1/4, t]  , {t, Ti, Tf}]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between NDSolve and NDSolveValue?

Comment: NDSolveValue returns an interpolation-function.

Comment: Just one more thing I wanted to ask. What is the use of '[[1]]' at the end of NDSolveValue?

Comment: Without `[[1]]` you get a list as a result. You could easily test it yourself...